# IOS Google Map Custom InfoWindow Xib error

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, xib

[image]

Hello!

I want to make Custom Marker InfoWindow Using Swift & Xib

1. Create Xib - size width:200 / Height: 200
2. But Not change Size in App
3. So I'm doing set size in program programmatically
   Infowindow.frame.size.width = 200
   Infowindow.frame.size.height = 200
4. Now change size!

by the way, I want to change size in Xib,
but It was now working...
How can I do?[image]

Comment: add UILabel, UIButton Things It is show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set delegate:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate
```

In your viewDidLoad() method

```
mapView.delegate = self
```